# Quckiblox ios SDK crashes on all API calls

Tags: ios, quickblox

I am developing an app using Quckiblox (Swift 2, iOS 9) and all attempts to make an API call produce the following error:

> 2015-10-04 04:46:06.411 Twister[1964:846268] +[QBRequest signUp:successBlock:errorBlock:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1000f7358
>   2015-10-04 04:46:06.415 Twister[1964:846268] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[QBRequest signUp:successBlock:errorBlock:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1000f7358'

The SDK was installed with Cocoapods and it's being set up like:

```
func setup() {
    print("Setting up Quickblox...")
    QBApplication.sharedApplication().applicationId = UInt(AppConfiguration.Quickblox.ApplicationID.description)!
    QBConnection.registerServiceKey(AppConfiguration.Quickblox.AuthorizationKey.description)
    QBConnection.registerServiceSecret(AppConfiguration.Quickblox.AuthorizationSecret.description)
    QBSettings.setAccountKey(AppConfiguration.Quickblox.AccountKey.description)
}
```

This is the faulty call:

```
QBRequest.signUp(user, successBlock: { response, user -> Void in
        print("Sign up successfull:\n \(user)")
        })
        { response -> Void in
        print(response.error)
    }
```

Any ideas on what might be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure you have opened xcworkspace and NOT xcodeproj.
2. I have tested your code and everything works, so problem is that Xcode can not find .framework symbols, it finds only headers

Comment: It seems that the problem is when Quickblox is compiled as a framework. Unfortunately, cocoapods require that all projects be compiled the same way.

Comment: If I remove the use_frameworks from the podfile everything works.

Comment: We are looking for better solution to compile our framework as dylib, but as for now you should remove use_frameworks from pod file

Answer (score 0):

May be this is late but it may help someone in future
 i have faced same problem and that was solved by

> Add -lxml2, -ObjC flags to Other Linker Flags section in project settings

[Official doc link](http://quickblox.com/developers/IOS-how-to-connect-Quickblox-framework)

If still error occurs check if any framework is missing